# How to use document.getElementById() method in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, dom

I am trying to reset HTML Form in order to clear all the values in the input fields using;

```
document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
```

But I can use that in typescript, it's giving me an error saying `document.getElementById('myForm') may be null`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Also, if `myForm` is not found, then it could indeed be a problem. TS doesn't know the layout of your page.

Comment: If you’re really sure the element exists, you could work around the default typing using `!`: `document.getElementById('myForm')!.reset()`.

Comment: I'm using it with AngularJs, It's the controller where I can find `myForm`, But the problem is its giving me an error saying document.getElementById('myForm') may be null before compiling.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert `document.getElementById('myForm')!` this will work but later if i add `.reset()` it says `[ts] Property 'reset' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
any`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Typescript will force you to check the value is not null if you use the `strictNullChecks` option (or `strict` which includes `strictNullChecks`). You can either perform the test or use a not null assertion (!). Also you will need to use a type assertion to assert the html element is an `HTMLFormElement` as by default it will be just an `HtmlElement` and `reset` is present only `HTMLFormElement`

Just an assertion Assertion:

```
(document.getElementById('myForm') as HTMLFormElement).reset();
```

Assertion with check (recommended):

```
let form = document.getElementById('myForm')
if(form) (form as HTMLFormElement).reset();
```

Not null assertion (if you want to access just `HtmlElement` member):

```
document.getElementById('myForm')!.click()
```

Comment: Non null assertions are forbidden in ts > 3.4.5, just use assertion (the first one).

Comment: @Takatalvi Why are they forbidden? This is news to me, could you please provide some docs to that? Maybe you have a lint rule forbidding them but they are still a fuly supported part of the language

Comment: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-non-null-assertion/

Comment: @Takatalvi a tslint rule is just a lint rule. One can opt into it or not. There are plenty of code bases that do not opt into forbidding this operator, the TS compiler team being one of them. There is also a TS lint rule that forces you to specify all types which I personally find to be a horrible idea. Opting blindly into every rule is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I misunderstood the warning.

Comment: Based on your helpful TypeScript type casting answer here, I'm hoping you might be able to help me with this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67522592/470749 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are different fixes for this. You can edit your tsconfig.json and add

```
"strictNullChecks": false
```

to it. This will disable the strict null checks.

If you are absolutely sure that the element exists, you could also use `!` to tell typescript that your id will always be there

```
document.getElementById('myForm')!.reset();
```

Or if you want to make sure to never get an error because the element indeed doesn't exist, check for its existance

```
const el = document.getElementById('myForm');
if (el) el.reset();
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('myForm')!` this will pass the null error but later if i add  `.reset()` then it says `[ts] Property 'reset' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
any`

Answer (score 0):

Just use this syntax & it will work :

`document.getElementById('myForm')!`

Comment: document.getElementById('myForm')!

Answer (score 0):

try use typing like this:

```
const myForm = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('myForm')
if(myForm ) myForm.reset();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try a check on the element. Something like:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
if(myForm) myForm.reset();
```