# Typescript Select element by id

Tags: typescript

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong ? I have btn. I select this btn by id and I would like to massage it during processing. I am getting error. Object is possibly 'null'

```
 <button className='btn btn-primary rounded-0' id='loadBtn'>Upload Image</button>
```

in js, or in react I would do this way, but in typescript is red underline.

```
document.getElementById('loadBtn').textContent = 'Processing...'
```

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52491832/535275

Comment: This way is working for me: const btn = document.getElementById('loadBtn') as HTMLFormElement    and then    btn.textContent = 'Processing...'    Is any other way how to do it? Thank you